# Authentication: Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient)

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, localdb

I have been using "(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB" as my database, and because I don't know SQL commands, I used "Linq to SQL Classes" to connect to the database and tables.

Now its the problem, I'm just using "Linq to SQL" to connect to the database and the "(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB" authentication is set to "Windows Authentication", and because of that, I cannot run the application on another PC. it will give me this error:

> Cannot open database "C:\USERS\******.MDF" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'blah\blah'

I tried to change the authentication mode to the "SQL Server Authentication" but it won't accept any username password and will show this error:

> The attempt to attach to the database failed with the following information: login failed for user 'blah'.

What should I do to run my application on other PCs without worrying about the authentication, Can I just remove the authentication completely?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to deploy the database to the other PC along with the application, or are you attempting to use your PC as a networked server (database on your PC, application on another)?

Comment: The first one, I'm just coping the application and (mdf,ldf) files along with it.

Comment: I'm using **SQL SERVER EXPRESS** by the way.

Comment: And you’ve verified that they have SQL server Express on their server, and that the database has been mounted?

Comment: yea actually it's a VPS and I'm the one who installed the "SQL server express" on both PCs. when the database is empty it can run on any pc, but when it gets filled in one system it will only run on that specific PC.
As I know, I have to add a user with "SQL Server Object Explorer" and use that instead of "Windows Authentication" right?

Comment: No necessarily; you just have to ensure that the windows accounts on both machines are members of the same group, and that group has the appropriate permissions. For example, if both accounts are Local Administrators, then you can use that group.

Comment: Yea you are right, thanks a lot man. Send an answer so I can choose it as Accepted Answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to ensure that the windows accounts on both machines are members of the same group, and that group has the appropriate permissions. For example, if both accounts are Local Administrators, then you can use that group

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "(LocalDb)" use the actual machine name of your computer.  It looks from the error message that on the other computer it is looking for a copy of the local SQL Server engine but not finding it.

Using the server name instead of LocalDb will make it look for the other computer's copy of SQL Server and connect there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as it looks its finding the database, but it can't connect to it due to authentication:
{Error: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process.}

Comment: Are you using local Windows accounts or Domain ones?  If local then the same user and password need to exist on both machines for Windows Auth to work.

Comment: I'm using local users. Thank you dude, ill consider that too.